# RecyclerView content is disappearing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

after minimizing or opening other app my content is loosing and I need to fill recycler view again

P.S. in manifest I have

```
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

recyclerView

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/booking_rec"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
      android:background="#ECEFF1">

   </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

adapter

```
public class RecAdapterBooking extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecAdapterBooking.CustomViewHolder> {
    private List<Booking> bookingList;
    private Context context;

    public RecAdapterBooking(List<Booking> bookingList, Context context) {
        this.bookingList = bookingList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecAdapterBooking.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.booking_view_item, parent, false);
        CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecAdapterBooking.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Booking booking = bookingList.get(position);

        String name = booking.getUser().getFirstName() + " " + booking.getUser().getLastName();
        String date = booking.getStartTime().toString() + " - " + booking.getToTime().toString();

        holder.name.setText(booking.getName());
        holder.user.setText(name);
        holder.dateTime.setText(date);
        holder.type.setText(booking.getType().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bookingList.size();
    }

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView name;
        protected TextView user;
        protected TextView dateTime;
        protected TextView type;

        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            this.user = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user);
            this.dateTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_time);
            this.type=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.booking_type);

        }
    }
}
```

mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

List<Room> roomList = new ArrayList<>();
static List<Booking> bookingList = new ArrayList<>();
static RecyclerView recyclerView;
static RecAdapterBooking recAdapterBooking;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    Helper.initList(roomList);

    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

    for (Room r : roomList) {
        menu.add(r.getName());
    }

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.booking_rec);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy");
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_view);
    setTime(c, df, textView);

    ImageButton leftButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.left);
    ImageButton rightButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.right);
    leftButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
            textView.setText(df.format(c.getTime()));
        }
    });
    rightButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
            textView.setText(df.format(c.getTime()));
        }
    });

    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this).getBoolean("pref", true)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleRoomActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }

}

public void setTime(Calendar c, SimpleDateFormat df, TextView textView) {
    final String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    textView.setText(formattedDate);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

//settings-ზე დაჭერის activity
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        ArrayList<String> roomNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Room r : roomList) {
            roomNameList.add(r.getName());
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("roomlist", roomNameList);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_log_out) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


//მენიუდან არჩეული ოთახის განრიგის გამოტანა
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    for (Room r : roomList) {
        if (item.getTitle().equals(r.getName())) {
            bookingList = r.getBookingList();
            recAdapterBooking = new RecAdapterBooking(bookingList, MainActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recAdapterBooking);
            setTitle(r.getName());
            break;
        }
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: which device are you testing on ?

Comment: tablet and smartphone too, does it matter ?

Comment: looks like your activity/fragment is restarted after your app is opened from minimize state. Happens usually on device with low ram

Comment: Please paste here implementation of lifecycle methods. It may help us find out what is wrong.

Comment: it's nexus 10 and xperia zr (ram 2gb), I don't think it's problem of ram :/

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because of lifecycle. When you minimizes your app on pause is called, then on Stop. When you maximizes your app, on Start are called. Probably you're setting your content on OnCreate. This way, if your app is killed while you're using the other, when you open it again onCreate won't be called, this way you're not placing the content again.

To fix it, you can call the submit list method in on start or on resume too. OnStart is a better method to do so.